# Using CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture1, CompletableFuture2), still response time is high

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

I have a list of elements(`List<SummaryList>`) which needs to be passed to two other services and those two services should run `asynchronously` using `CompletableFuture`.
I have used below logic but still it takes lot of time to respond.
If `list` below is of 5-6 elements, response time is 2-3 sec, but when the `list` has 10-25 elements, the response time is >10 sec in order to complete the two service calls.
Am I missing something as part of optimization/running asynchronously? Is there any other way to optimize these calls?
I have below class `SummaryList` which contains properties like `id, account, name and type`

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    Class SummaryList {
        private String id;
        private String account;
        private String name;
        private String type;
        public SummaryList() {}
        public SummaryList(String id, String account, String name, 
        String type) {
          this.id=id;
          this.account=account;
          this.name=name;
          this.type=type;
        }
    }
```

I have the values of `id and account`.
Using `account`, I need to call two other services(`invokeFirstService` & `invokeSecondService`) asynchronously to populate `name and type` of `SummaryList`.
And these two services use this `account` as input.
`invokeFirstService` & `invokeSecondService` functions below return `CompletableFuture<Void>`.
`invokeFirstService` populates `name` and `invokeSecondService` populates `type`

```
  SummaryList s1=new SummaryList("101","account1","","");
  SummaryList s2=new SummaryList("102","account2","","");
  SummaryList s3=new SummaryList("103","account3","","");
  SummaryList s4=new SummaryList("104","account4","","");
  SummaryList s5=new SummaryList("105","account5","","");
  List<SummaryList> list=Arrays.asList(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5);


    for (SummaryList summary : list) {
                FirstRequestBean firstRequestBean = new FirstRequestBean();                                                      
                SecondRequestBean secondRequestBean = new SecondRequestBean();
                FirstResponseBean firstResponseBean = new FirstResponseBean();
                SecondResponseBean secondResponseBean = new SecondResponseBean();
                firstRequestBean.setAccount(summary.getAccount());                                                  
                secondRequestBean.setAccount(summary.getAccount());
                CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                try {                          
                invokeFirstService(firstRequestBean,firstResponseBean).get();
                if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(firstResponseBean.getResponse())) {                                          
                summary.setName(firstResponseBean.getResponse().get(0).getName());
               }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                     //throw e;
                   }
                }), CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
               try {
               invokeSecondService(secondRequestBean, secondResponseBean).get();
               if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(secondResponseBean.getResponse())) {                                                   
               summary.setType(secondResponseBean.getResponse().get(0).getType());                                                                                                                                    
               }
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                        //throw e;
                      }
                })).join();
            }
```

Comment: try use method with given executor instead of method with default executor.

CompletableFuture<Void> runAsync(Runnable runnable, Executor executor)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried using `Executor`, still it takes long time to respond. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1: Looking at your snippet, the **underlying operation is IO intensive**.

Whenever we work with IO intensive tasks with multiple thread the **thread pool size should be bigger than the number of available processors**.

So, first optimization would be using a custom dedicated thread pool.

2: Avoid using **join()** try to refactor your code so that you don't wait upon the response and implement your "after-logic" using **thenApply/thenCompose/thenCombine call-back processing** methods provided by **CompletableFuture**.

Something like:

```java
CompletableFuture.allOf(...).thenApply(response -> {
      //handling
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Ankit. Per your 1st suggestion, I tried using `Executors` with individual `CompletableFutures` that are passed as arguments of `allOf` function. Per 2nd suggestion used `thenRunAsync` after `allOf` function and added post call logic, still I see higher response time. Am I doing something wrong and so they are not running in parallel and hence taking longer time?

Comment: Are you using join() or get() anywhere in your code?

Comment: Yes Ankit I endedup using alteast one `join()` at the end or else, the two service calls I am making returns `null` response. Is there any alternative to trigger those calls without using `get` or `join`?